# Function Structure Issue: 'track_plot' Error with No 'p' Argument

Tags: bioinformatics, genomics

Good morning, I am trying to run this code using the "track_plot" function and I get this error that I cannot resolve. The structure of the function is as follows, and there is no "p" argument. Is it a problem related to the structure of the function itself? The examples on the browser don't work either and give the same error. How can it be solved?

`trackplot::track_plot(summary_list = t, col = track_cols, show_ideogram = TRUE, peaks = CTCF_peak_files) Error in layout.matrix(mat = matrix(data = data), heights = lo_heights) : argument "p" is missing, with no default`

Problem Resolution and something else

Comment: This is the GitHub link: https://github.com/PoisonAlien/trackplot